# Unable to read tab separated values in PHP using fscanf()

Tags: php, scanf

I have not used the fscanf function much. I am trying to solve this problem on hacker earth, where they allow the program to be tested by feeding it with some input. The input is treated as a file, it seems, because fscanf is used to read it. Following is the input I am trying to parse -

```
1
50  40  30
```

(2nd line contains tab separated values)

Following is my code -

```
fscanf(STDIN, "%s\n", $test_cases);
echo "Test ".$test_cases;

fscanf(STDIN, "%d\t%d\t%d\n", $space_sep_vals);
echo "\n\nOutput ".$space_sep_vals;
```

And following is my output -

```
Test 1

Output
```

**Nothing is parsed by the 2nd fscanf().**

If I change it to -

```
fscanf(STDIN, "%d\n", $space_sep_vals);
```

It parses the first number. Output -

```
Test 1

Output 50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
fscanf(STDIN, "%d\t%d\t%d\n", $space_sep_vals);
```

The format string of [`fscanf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php) contains 3 conversion specifiers `%d` but you provided only one variable to store the read values.

Because of insufficient arguments, `fscanf()` triggers a Warning (you probably don't see because your PHP is wrongly configured to hide them) and returns without reading anything in `$space_sep_vals`.

Always pass to `fscanf()` (and any other function from the `printf()`/`scanf()` family the correct number of arguments matching the number of conversion specifiers provided in the format string and they will work as described in the docs.

Comment: Ah, got it.. Thanks! I was expecting the entire parsed thing into a single variable. It has been a long time since I used scanf() functions in C :D