# How to read tab sepereated values in PHP using fscanf

Tags: php

Recently I was practicing problems in Hackearth and I was unable to scan tab-separated values.

Ex(Inputs): 12 3 6 1

The input is treated as a file, it seems, because fscanf is used to read it.

I was trying to scan it using while loop like this:

```
$arr = [];
$i = 0;
while($i < 4){
 fscanf(STDIN, "%s\t", $a);
 $arr[] = $a;
 $i++;
}
```

But when I am printing $arr like:

```
print_r($arr);
```

It shows like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 12
    [3] => 12
)
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247204/unable-to-read-tab-separated-values-in-php-using-fscanf) problem but unable to solve my problem.

How can I scan all the numbers using a loop and put it in an array?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php):

> Each call to `fscanf()` reads one line from the file.

So you can't call `fscanf()` in a loop to read each number from the same line. The second iteration tries to read the next line, but there isn't one.

You can use `fgets()` to read a whole line, then use `explode()` to split it into an array at the delimiters:

```
$line = fgets(STDIN);
$line = rtrim($line); // remove the newline
$arr = explode("\t", $line);
```

Or use `fgetcsv()` to do this in one step:

```
$arr = fgetcsv(STDIN, 0, "\t");
```

Comment: Didn't worked. It is still printing the first value always.

Comment: You're right. It works if each number is on a separate line, but not on the same line. The remaining `fscanf()` calls are getting an error for some reason.

Comment: I see: the documentation says: **Each call to fscanf() reads one line from the file.**